# Is there API to GET project users' services access?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Is there a way to get which services users have access to in a/all project/s? If so, is the best approach from Account -> Projects -> Users -> Services OR Users/Members -> Projects -> Services?

Thank you!

Comment: Nice.  If it's a bad question, please let me know.  Running away with a -1 without a word is just weak and not helpful.

Comment: I cannot find the page with the path you specified. Do you want to use our BIM360 API to query the service admins of a specific project?

Comment: @EasonKang I am trying to create a log/report/dashboard of all users on a BIM 360 site showing which projects they are on as well as the services they are assigned to.

Comment: I provide some insight below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2020/03/30**

Project User API is under beta https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-project-users-bim-360-finally-here, please have a try, thanks!

=========End line=======

I'm not 100% sure about the services you mentioned, But here is a workaround for obtaining the project list of a specific user:

1.Call [GET Account users](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/) to get `uid` of a user

```
[
  {
    "id": "a75e8769-621e-40b6-a524-0cffdd2f784e",
    //...
    "name": "John Smith",
    "nickname": "Johnny",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "uid": "L9EBJKCGCXBB",        //!<<< The value is going to pass to x-user-id
    //...
  }
]
```

2.Call [GET hubs/:hub_id/projects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/) with a request header `x-user-id` to get projects that a user belongs to

```
curl -X GET \
  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/{HUD_ID}/projects \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'x-user-id: L9EBJKCGCXBB'
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, Eason. I'm referring to BIM 360 services (Field, Coordinate, Docs, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I am not too sure what you are trying to achieve as I am not super familiar with BIM 360.
However, could you get what you are looking for by using theses from the Forge Data Management API?

From the Hubs API, you should be able to get the list of Hubs a user have access to:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/

You can also check permissions for a user using the CheckPermission API:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/CheckPermission/

Answer (score 1):

Also look at [GET Account Users](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/) for roles.

Comment: I appreciate your response!  That does give user statistics but not what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not possible... yet. I recieved a response from Autodesk Forge developers:

"Unfortunately that is not exactly possible for now but what I will do is to raise a feature request with Engineering and hopefully

Will let you know if they need more info to assess our request. Thanks!"

Thank you everyone who helped!